# Computing $f(\gamma(t))$ in the context of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $(M,g$) is a Riemannian manifold and $U$ is a normal neighborhood of $p\in M$.

I am given a smooth curve $\gamma(t):[0,c] \to U$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$.

Suppose I also have  an $f\in C^\infty (U)$. Then the composition $f\circ \gamma:[0,c]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

My confusion is I have no idea how to compute what $\frac{d}{dt} f\circ\gamma(t)$ is. According to page 162 of John Lee's book on Riemannian manifolds, it should be $df(\gamma'(t))$.

Can someone explain this  to me?

Comment: Isn't $df$ pretty much defined so that $df_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t)):= (f\circ \gamma)'(t)$?

Comment: Can you now explain why this is equal to $<grad(r)|_{\gamma(t)} ,|\gamma'(t)|>$?

Comment: THat is by definition of $\text{grad}(f)$. The gradient vector field of a function is that vector field obtained by using the musical isomorphism of the metric tensor so as to make the equation $df(X)=g(\text{grad}(f),X)\equiv \langle\text{grad}(f), X\rangle$ true for all smooth functions $f$ and all smooth vector fields $X$ (you can also of course look at this pointwise).